# Controlling default direction of multi column order

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have a table which contains a name column and a date column (among others).

When a user sorts by the name column (in either direction) I would like to order the date column in DESC order. This is what I have so far:

```
columns: [
    {data: 'compliance', name: 'compliance', searchable: false},
    {data: 'resident.last_name', name: 'resident.last_name'},
    {data: 'accident_date', name: 'accident_date', searchable: false},
    {data: 'status', name: 'status'},
],
columnDefs: [
    { "orderData": [ 1, 2 ], "targets": 1 },
],
```

Currently, if a user sorts the name column in ascending order it sorts the date in ascending order too. Similarly, if they sort name in descending order the date gets sorted in descending order.

I would like the date column to be shown in descending order even when the name column is set to ascending.

If possible, I would still like to maintain the default behaviour whereby a user can shift-click columns to set their own preference for multi-column sorting.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it happens this isn't possible with DataTables at the moment. Here's the author's response:

> Unfortunately there is no way to do this I'm afraid. The additional columns for columns.orderData can currently only match the ordering direction of the host column.
>
> That is a limitation I'm aware of and want to address in future.

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/106728#Comment_106728